# Getting values of XML tags with special characters and keywords in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a tag in an XML file as "trans-date"

I have loaded the XML file using simpleXML in PHP as

`$xml = simplexml_load_file('studentdb.xml');`

Now I want to retrieve the value if trans-date field. I have written the code as:

`$tdate=$xml->trans-date;`

But this line of code is not returning the expected value because "-" is being considered as a minus operator and date as a keyword;

I tried using:

`$tdate=$xml->trans."-date";`

But this is not working as well. How do I get the value of that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`$tdate=$xml->{'trans-date'};`